# Check file size while writing file and create new file

Tags: java

I am trying to write java code to write ".dat" File. While writing, check size as well. Every 200 KB create new ".dat" file and continue to write file. Is there any way that I can do that?

When file is bigger than 200KB, create a new one like this:

1st file name: 1_filename 
2nd file name: 2_filename 
3rd file name: 3_filename 
... 
or if only one file is created (meaning it is smaller than 200KB) then:

file name: filename

I wrote the code, but it's only writing 2 files, so that's not the right way to do it.

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class xmlfile1filebytes {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    
    File folder = new File ("07072013");
    File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
    
    System.out.println("There are " + listOfFiles.length + " files"); 
    String filesin;
    
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy[HH.mm.ss]")
     .format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
     System.out.println(timeStamp);
     
    BufferedWriter xmlfile = null;
    BufferedWriter datfile = null;
  
    String outxmlfile = ("07072013\\" + timeStamp + ".xml");
    xmlfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outxmlfile));
    
    String outdatfile = ("07072013\\" + timeStamp + ".dat");
    datfile = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outdatfile));
    
    int offset = 0;
    int size = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
       
        File f = listOfFiles[i];
        
       // System.out.println(i + " " + f.getAbsolutePath());
        if (f.isFile()) {

            filesin = listOfFiles[i].getName();

            if (filesin.endsWith("pdf")) {
               
                Path aPath = Paths.get(f.getAbsolutePath()); 
       
                System.out.println(filesin);
                
                byte[] actualBytes = Files.readAllBytes(aPath);
                size = actualBytes.length;
             
                xmlfile.append((i + 1) + ")" + " File = " + filesin + ", Offset = " + offset + ", Size = " + size + "\n");
               
           
                offset = offset + size;
                xmlfile.newLine();
            
                String s = new String(actualBytes);
            
                datfile.append(s);
                datfile.newLine();
                
                
                File datfileinfolder = new File ("07072013\\" + timeStamp + ".dat");
                
                long datfilesize = datfileinfolder.length();
                long datfilesizeinkb = datfilesize /1024;
                
                System.out.println(datfilesizeinkb);
                
                if (datfilesizeinkb >= 200) {
                     datfile.close();

                      BufferedWriter datfile1 = null;
                      String outdatfile1 = ("07072013\\" + "1_"+ timeStamp + ".dat");
                      datfile1 = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outdatfile1));
                     
                      String s1 = new String(actualBytes);
                      datfile1.append(s1);
                      datfile1.close();
                }
                
                
             }
        }
    }
    
     xmlfile.close();
  }
}
```

And I get an error when the file is bigger than 400 KB.

ERROR:

```
There are 10 files
07-09-2013[16.03.00]
1192970_eBill_20130709.pdf
96
1321470_eBill_20130709.pdf
208
1724897_eBill_20130709.pdf
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedWriter.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Writer.write(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.Writer.append(Unknown Source)
    at xmlfile1filebytes.main(xmlfile1filebytes.java:65)
```

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you create a separate class whose only job it is to create files (in sequence), write data to the file, keep an eye on the size, and close / open files as needed. This will make your code more organized - you will be able to see your mistakes more clearly. The class would have the following methods:

```
setMax(maxVal)                 - set the maximum file size (default 400k)
setRoot(rootPath)              - folder where files will be created
setName(rootName)              - "format string" used to generate file names 
                                 (e.g. "myFile%03d.dat")
writeData(dataSize, dataBlock) - write data. If no file open, open it. 
                                 If file too big, split it.  
closeFile()                    - flush buffers, close the last file.
                                 Could be part of the destructor
currentFile()                  - returns name of current file (for debug)
currentSize()                  - returns current file size (for debug)
```

If you can figure out how to write this class you will solve your initial problem and have something you can re-use at the same time.

If you want to stay with (mostly) the code structure you already have, then your fix is to remove your current line 85.

```
         83:         String s1 = new String(actualBytes);
         84:         datfile1.append(s1);
         85:         datfile1.close();  <<<<<<<<<<< remove this line
         86:      }
```

Once you have closed the file, your next attempt to write to it will fail - and that's the error you are seeing.

Comment: I edit in my post..update code.. please check it!! Thanks!! actually I write to create new file.. I don't think that's right way to do it..Please help me.. Thanks!!

Comment: Your problem is that on line 85 you close the file you just opened... and next time you try to do `datfile1.append(s)` , the file is closed.

Comment: I need to create new file every 200KB soo.. if file writing is 800 KB 4 file should be created.. file name is 1_filename,2_filename,3_filename,4_filename...And if file write less than 200 KB than filename is same file name filename.... Please help me.. i think my way is wrong to create s1 or s2.. because i don't know size total size.. if there is 50000KB than I need to write 25000 file to be created.. I think my way is wrong.. I think you waty is good..

Comment: ohh ok!! Thanks.. Please help me.. please.. its really confusing to me.. every 200KB create new file.... that's all.. but its really hard for me!! please help me..

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 8 (or maybe Java 7), there is a better way to check file size (and take action accordingly)

```
if(Files.size(Paths.get(csvFile.toURI())) > 3000000 ){
// Create a new file at same path and use from next time - if current file is greater than X MB
}
```